# How do I make text flow through 2 rows of 2 columns using css3?

Tags: css, webkit

At the moment I've got a div which is 1024px wide.

In that box are two CSS3 columns with text flowing automatically from one to the next.

However, I want to restrict the height of these two columns to 700px - once they are full I want 2 more columns with the same height to appear underneath them.

Is this possible?

Comment: "I've got a div" can we see ? ;)

Comment: I guess you would like to build smth. like this: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2011/10/10/building-rich-text-centric-pages-in-ie10.aspx. Am I right?

Comment: This is now being addressed by Adobe's CSS3 regions proposal http://www.adobe.com/devnet/html5/articles/css3-regions.html

Answer (score 1):

OK. It is totally possible to achieve what I think you are about to build. However, if you want to do it by yourself, you will need a bit more then just CSS3 styles in place. You will need a fair amount of JavaScript as well.

Take a look at [this Columnizer jQuery plugin](http://welcome.totheinter.net/columnizer-jquery-plugin/) (it can do the job)

Here's a sample site showing results of it's work: http://welcome.totheinter.net/autocolumn/sample10.html

Comment: Hey, Thanks for the reply nowaq... so I've already made the box model with a two column flow and was hoping there was a css3 way of making the text flow into another set of columns - shame there isn't really. You can't really have two columns of text that extend so low the reader has to scroll down to read the first... then all the way back up to start reading the second. I'd spotted Columnizer today but glad you recommended it, I'll give it a shot. If anyone wants to chime in and suggest a css3 way let me know!

Answer (score 1):

Update on this:

The Adobe CSS Regions proposal mentioned by gimme5 looks excellent. Unfortunately, according to caniuse.com, there now seems to have very little browser support - it's been removed from current versions of Webkit.

There is a simpler proposal which may do the required job: CSS Multi-column layout (http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-multicol/) which appears to have broader browser support. I haven't tried it yet, but it might work for you without having to pile in a ton of Javascript.